# how to add application name secondly in manifest

Tags: android

I added first inherited class in manifest

```
    <application
    android:name=".GlobalApplication"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

and I want to add second application `ModelViewerApplication.class` inherited class because I have to use two application inherited classes.

Comment: every app have only single application class.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `<application>` doesn't support multiple `Application` classes. If you want to add second class extending `Application` then best you can do is:

```
public class SecondClass extends GlobalApplication {
...
}
```

In your manifest

```
<application
    android:name=".SecondClass"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
    >
```